# My class is not recognised (error: "not a type")

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a game in C++ using Allegro, and I created a simple Rectangle class, but it appears to somehow be out of scope in my main program, I have:

#### Vector2.h

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#ifndef __VECTOR2_H
#define __VECTOR2_H

using namespace std;

struct Vector2
{
public:
    float X,Y;
    Vector2() { }
    Vector2(const Vector2&) { }
    Vector2(const float& x, const float& y) : X(x), Y(y) { }
    ~Vector2( ) { }
    Vector2 operator+(const Vector2& v);
    Vector2 operator-(const Vector2& v);
};

#endif
```

#### Rectangle.h

```
#include "Vector2.h"

#ifndef __RECTANGLE_H_
#define __RECTANGLE_H_

using namespace std;

class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle() { }
    Rectangle(const Rectangle& r);
    Rectangle(const float& x,const float& y,const float& h,const float& w);
    ~Rectangle() { }
    void SetPosX(const float& x);
    void SetPosY(const float& y);
    void SetHeight(const float& h);
    void SetWidth(const float& w);

    bool Intersects(const Rectangle* r);

    Vector2* GetIntersection(const Rectangle* r);

    float x,y,w,h;
};


#endif
```

#### Main

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"

using namespace std;

// Other functions...

void myDraw(ALLEGRO_BITMAP* texture, Rectangle source, Rectangle dest, ALLEGRO_COLOR tint, Vector2 scale, float angle, int flags) //<-- This is where the error message points
{
    al_draw_tinted_scaled_rotated_bitmap_region(texture,
    source.x, source.y, source.w, source.h,
    tint,
    dest.x, dest.x, dest.w, dest.h,
    scale.X, scale.Y,
    angle, flags);

    return;
}
```

Help?

The specific error I'm getting is ***main.cpp(147): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Rectangle'***

Comment: Do you really have two files with different content named Rectangle.h? Which one is included? Do you see the Vector2 structure?

Comment: Sorry, that was just my mistake in copying the code over; the first Rectangle.h should have been Vector2.h (Fixed).

Comment: What happens if you exclude Vector2.h from Rectangle.h? Is the error message the same?

Comment: Then it complains that Vector2 is not a type in Rectangle.h

Comment: Have you tried to define your Rectangle class to be public?

Comment: yes, I get one additional error: "error C3381: 'Rectangle' : assembly access specifiers are only available in code compiled with a /clr option" are you saying that the class __itself__ needs to be declared public? I know that class __members__ are private by default, but I thought the class itself would be implicitly public.

Comment: @LajosArpad - this isn't java.